# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity 404 Error

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm working in Azure Data Factory and have a Rest API data pipeline with a sink to Azure SQL DB.

Linked Service and datasets set up and tested.

Running Oauth2 so have access token saved to keyvault and retrieve that fine.

I can run a web activity to call the API and the call is successful.

Authorization headers for the bearer access token entered in web activity and copy activity.

If i run a copy activity with same rest linked service, dataset, url and authorization headers and i get a 404 not found error.

If i try to preview in the copy activity i get the 404 error even though url and authorization headers all look correct as they work in the web activity.

i have tried other API call with the copy activity and can run those with no issue so its this specific API service I am experiencing an issue.

I can save the web activity down to SQL so the sink is not the issue.

Any suggestions on what i can do to try fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: check you are usiong correct base url and relative url

Answer (score 0):

Try using http connector instead and see if it works.

You can use this HTTP connector to:

- Retrieve data from an HTTP/S endpoint by using the HTTP GET or POST
  methods.
- Retrieve data by using one of the following authentications:
  Anonymous, Basic, Digest, Windows, or ClientCertificate.
- Copy the HTTP response as-is or parse it by using supported file formats and
  compression codecs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?source=recommendations&tabs=data-factory